# Python String to Java byte[]

Tags: jython

From what I have understood, A Python 2 string (type `str`) is nothing but a sequence of bytes. How do I convert such a string to a Java byte array, explicit?

A naive attempt that doesn't work:

```python
from jarray import array
myStr = 'some str object'
myJavaArr = array(myStr, 'b') # TypeError: Type not compatible with array type
```

My reason to this is that when Jython implicitly converts a Python String to Java code, it converts it to a Java String, incorrectly because it doesn't know the encoding of the `str`.

Answer (score 5):

I found an utility method that does the trick:

```python
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil
myJavaArr = StringUtil.toBytes(myStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach of passing a `str` object to `jarray.array()` worked in Jython 2.5 and earlier.

Now you must convert the `str` to a sequence of numbers first (eg list, tuple, or [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray)):

```
myStr = 'some str object'
myJavaArr = array( bytearray(myStr), 'b')
```

or

```
myStr = 'some str object'
myList = [ord(ch) for ch in myStr]
myJavaArr = array( myList, 'b')
```

(see also https://sourceforge.net/p/jython/mailman/message/35003179/)

Note, too, that Java's `byte` type is *signed*.  The conversion will fail if any of your integers have a value outside the range -128..127.  If you are starting with *unsigned* byte values in Python, you'll need to convert them.  (eg apply this to each value: `if 0x80 <= i <= 0xFF: i = i - 256`)